# cordova-plugin-facebook4 don't send logEvent

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-facebook-plugin, cordova-facebook

I'm using `ionic` with plugin `cordova-plugin-facebook4`.
When I try to use `logEvent()` I didn't receive any error and also didn't get the information to my Facebook analytics.

I used `logEvent()` in the following way:

```
facebookConnectPlugin.logEvent('my event name', {}, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using arbitrary Strings as Event names are allowed. For e.g.

```
Facebook.logEvent('InvoicePage', {}, 1).then(function (value) {console.log('fulfilled logevent'); }, function (reason) {console.log('failed logevent'); });;
```

where Facebook is referred from :

```
import {Facebook} from "ionic-native";
```

One reason for the analytics not showing up is if you had to change the APP_ID or APP_NAME for some reason. To fix this, remove and install "cordova-plugin-facebook4" using

```
ionic plugin remove cordova-plugin-facebook4 --save
```

and reinstall using with the new values

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --variable APP_ID="new_app_id" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"
```

Answer (score 0):

According to their documentation, you can't log arbitrary strings as event names. You have to use their supported event constants, e.g. `FBSDKAppEventNameActivatedApp`, `FBSDKAppEventNameAddedPaymentInfo`, `FBSDKAppEventNameCompletedRegistration`, etc.

I assume you tried to log a random string that wasn't in their table of constants, which is why it didn't show up on your analytics dashboard.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/ios